# Portable default to current datetime with JPA

Tags: mysql, jpa, mariadb, h2, current-time

I wrote for my column

```
class MyEntity {

    @Column(columnDefinition="DATETIME(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private LocalDateTime createdDate = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

and it works in `MySQL` but fails in `H2` which I use for automated testing.

Is it possible to have default datetime serverside with `JPA` which is portable?

Comment: I guess that you are letting JPA handle the schema creation/updates. Do you really need the column default value at the SQL level - i.e. will something outside of JPA insert data in that table? JPA can create the date on a `@PrePersist` hook too.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos yes I need non-JPA code to write to the table

Answer (score 1):

#### Avoiding the problem by avoiding the "test database" H2

I would generally recommend to test your code using [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org) rather than with H2 to avoid any issues purely caused by translation,

#### Using a proxy to translate your SQL

If for some reason you need multi RDBMS support (possibly not just with H2), you could hook jOOQ's [`ParsingConnection`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/parsing-connection/) or `DataSource` in between when you generate your schema or run your JPA native SQL queries to make sure (most) MySQL specific stuff also works on H2.

[I've written a blog post on the jOOQ blog to explain how this could work](https://blog.jooq.org/using-jooq-to-write-vendor-agnostic-sql-with-jpas-native-query-or-formula/).

Comment: I am using it, and it is using H2 :)

Comment: Oh you're using jOOQ's `JPADatabase`? Hah, but you didn't mention that in your question! If that doesn't work, it might be a bug, though I can't reproduce a problem...

Comment: No, I am using `Quarkus` and `Quarkus` is using `testcontainers` and it is using `H2`... in the house that Jack built :D